# Android AWS SDk

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I am trying to access Amazon web Service :Simpledb via Android, i downloaded the androidawsSDk-1.3.3  and added the [necessary  Jar](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=101501)  in "libs" folder of my project and configured BuildPath. But i end up with either **Eclipse Freezing or DX warning :Ignoring innerclasses attributes for an anonymous innerclass (org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory $1).** I did try to clean and build the project again.Any Solutions for this problem?

Comment: I think that warning means the JARs are old, probably compiled for a different Java version. I checked the JAR you mentioned and the `LogFactory` class files were created in November 2007, so that makes sense. 

But also, this is a warning, not an error, so it shouldn't break the build. Is it?

Comment: @SteveBlackwell It breaks the build,The eclipse either freezes or throws error saying "Java Heap Space "

Answer (score 1):

I did these,

- `Right click Eclipse->Properties ->Target` **and**
- add the following `-vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m` ,
- clean and build it .

Its working fine now.